# Magento 1.8 - Hiding a field - is my method acceptable?

Tags: php, magento

I want to hide the COMPANY field from the Customer Account dashboard (don't ask why).

I found that the address is generated here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
```

I created a local version to override the core file and then changed `public function getAddressesCollection()` to the following:

```
public function getAddressesCollection()
{
    if ($this->_addressesCollection === null) {
        $this->_addressesCollection = $this->getAddressCollection()
            ->setCustomerFilter($this)
            //->addAttributeToSelect('*')

            ->addAttributeToSelect('prefix')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('middlename')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('suffix')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('street')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('city')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('country_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('region')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('region_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('postcode')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('telephone')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('fax')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_is_valid')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_request_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_request_date')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('vat_request_success');



        foreach ($this->_addressesCollection as $address) {
            $address->setCustomer($this);
        }
    }

    return $this->_addressesCollection;
}
```

I commented out the `addAttributeToSelect('*')` and replaced it with every customer_address attribute except for COMPANY.

Is this acceptable? It works but I want to know if it will have any obvious negative impact.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to hide the field? ;-)